# Matching multiple ranges with sed range expressions

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

Update: *As many commentators have pointed out, my question was ill-formed. Sorry and thank you! I am updating the my question but leaving the old question at the end for reference.*

**Updated question**
I want to extract lines between two given expressions (say regex's) and do this repeatedly until I reach the end of the file.

So given the input:

```
apple
hello
banana
world
brave
new
blueberries
hello
orange
fiddle
world
cup
```

And patterns `hello` and `world`, I want the output:

```
hello
banana
world
hello
orange
fiddle
world
```

If it helps I can assume there is no overlap, i.e., we never encounter two `hello`s before encountering a `world`.

**Old question**

`seq 20 | sed -n '4,6p'`

outputs the following:

```
4
5
6
```

But what I want is:

```
4
5
6
14
15
16
```

is there a way to do this using sed (or awk, or grep)? Thanks!

Comment: As the answer below mentions, the `4` and `6` in `sed 4,6p` are line numbers. Just that with your sample data, they also match the contents of the lines. So, an important question here is which one you mean? Do you want the particular lines regardless of content, or the lines which have a particular content?

Comment: It's great to provide an example as you did, but please describe more precisely what you want to achieve (the concept).

Comment: The right answer depends on what should happen if there's a "hello" towards  the bottom of the file without a subsequent "world", what do to if both strings appear on 1 line, whether you want a full or partial match, whether you really want a regexp match or actually a string match, etc. and none of that is testable given your current sample input/output. Think about the rainy day cases, not just the sunny day, as the latter are always trivial while the former much harder to handle.

Comment: Now, after your edit, it's a completely different (and trivial to answer: `sed '/hello/,/world/!d'`) question which invalidates all current answers. Please revert your edit and look for the many duplicates or sed FAQ for your new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have misunderstood what `4,6` does in `sed`. The only way the old question and the new one aren't totally different is if you wanted to extract rows based on contents (delimited by a start and end pattern) and not the row numbers. The usage of `seq` makes the formulation very ambiguous.

If you really meant to extract lines based on line number, [Nate T's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/676255/494713) and [they's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/676219/494713) answers are the only ones that actually generalize. However, if you want to filter based on row contents (as your updated question suggests), you're looking for pattern ranges. Specifically, if you're looking to extract what's between lines that end with `4` and the next line that ends with `6`, you're looking for:

```
seq 35 | sed -n "/4$/,/6$/p"
```

The start pattern (i.e., `4$`) and end pattern (i.e., `6$`) can be made arbitrarily complex to suit your needs (such as `hello` and `world`).

It really depends on your use case, but if you do want to filter based on contents and not line number, and you don't want to make any assumption on the order of the contents, here's an example of pattern ranges in action:

```
sed -n "/4$/,/6$/p" <<EOF 
heredoc> 1
heredoc> 2
heredoc> 3
heredoc> 4
heredoc> 14
heredoc> 15
heredoc> 5
heredoc> 6
heredoc> 7
heredoc> 14
heredoc> 14
heredoc> 14
heredoc> 16
heredoc> 16
heredoc> 15
heredoc> EOF
4
14
15
5
6
14
14
14
16
```

Note how `sed` always picks the first occurrence of the start and end patterns for a range, meaning that a range can contain multiple rows matching the start pattern but only one occurrence of the end pattern.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your `sed` expression prints line 4 through to 6, or rather, it calls the `p` command for the range of lines specified by the address `4,6`.  To additionally print lines 14 through to 16, call `p` for the address `14,16`.  You may add further editing expressions by separating them using `;` or newlines, or by supplying multiple `-e` options with arguments:

```bsh
$ seq 20 | sed -n -e '4,6p' -e '14,16p'
4
5
6
14
15
16
```

With `awk`, you'd do it in a similar way,

```bsh
$ seq 20 | awk 'NR == 4, NR == 6; NR == 14, NR == 16'
4
5
6
14
15
16
```

Or, if you always want the 4th, 5th, and 6th line of every group of 10 lines:

```bsh
$ seq 30 | awk 'NR%10 == 4, NR%10 == 6'
4
5
6
14
15
16
24
25
26
```

Using GNU `sed`, you'd get the same effect with

```bsh
sed -n -e '4~10p' -e '5~10p' -e '6~10p'
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed`, how about

```
seq 20|sed -n '4,6p;14,16p'
```

Or using `awk`

```
seq 20|awk 'NR>3&&NR<7||NR>13&&NR<17'
```

Supposing you wanted to match on line content, rather than line number, you could use either of these approaches.

```
seq 20|sed -n '/^4$/,/^6$/p;/^14$/,/^16$/p'
seq 20|awk '/^4$/,/^6$/;/^14$/,/^16$/'
```

Answer (score 2):

The `sed` command you're using isn't doing what you think it is. It is operating only on lines 4 through 6. The `4,6` you put in the command is a line range, its effects can be more clearly seen if you run `seq 5 15 | sed -n '4,6p'`. Then the bare `p` simply prints the line.

One way to get `grep` to do what you want is:

```
seq 20 | grep -e '[456]'
```

This isn't completely correct, since if you run

```
seq 50 | grep -e '[456]'
```

you'll get numbers that start with 4, 5, or 6, rather than only ending with that digit. I assume you want to print lines that end in your search string; though that's an assumption perhaps not warranted.

If you edit your question to give a more thorough explanation of what you want to occur, you'll likely get better help.

Comment: you can add the '$' end-of-line regex anchor to your regexp to make sure it matches only those numbers as the last digit: `seq 1 50 | grep '[456]$'`

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print the lines only once if they're within the given ranges, even if those ranges may overlap (like 4..6 and 5..7):

```
$ seq 20 | sed -e 4,6b -e 5,7b -e 9,10b -e d
4
5
6
7
9
10
```

```
$ seq 20 | perl -lne 'print if (4..6)|(5..7)|(9..10)'
4
5
6
7
9
10
```

(note that it's the binary `|`, not the logical `||`, as it's important all be tested so the lower end be seen for the range to be entered).

Compare with:

```
$ seq 20 | sed -n '4,6p; 5,7p; 9,10p'
4
5
5
6
6
7
9
10
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution I came up with looks a lot like the one posted by @they, but actually uses a different technique. I used the dual address format. Instead of using the first address to print `4, 5, & 6`, I used it to match `4, 14, etc.` and then used the `+N` syntax at the second to print the corresponding `*5` and `*6` for each instance.

The resulting command was

```
seq 20 | sed -n 4~10,+2p
```

Answer (score 1):

```
seq 20 | sed -e '/[0-37-9]$/d'
```

What you need to do is delete the lines you don't want.